CEC Line Connectivity from Multiple HDMI Inputs and Outputs
I am designing a board with multiple HDMI inputs and outputs. If I want this board to be CEC compliant, how should I connect the CEC lines from multiple HDMI inputs and outputs?
Regards,

It reads in the HDMI specfication and compliance test specification. Are you planning to go to official HDMI tests?

Yes, that's the plan. I am aware that CEC lines from all HDMI inputs and one HDMI output (repeater) shall be interconnected. What I am failing to understand is that does it mean there's only one CEC line going to the CEC controller for both HDMI input and one output? What about the remaining outputs?

It all depends what your device needs to do. You have followed the rules so far. The question is, how many CEC controllers you have and how do you intend your device to work with the outputs. Do you need CEC on the other outputs and why?

The device is an FPGA and I can have as many controllers as I need. The board will have 3 x HDMI RX and 3 x HDMI TX ports. I am trying to determine what's the best way to connect CEC line(s) to the FPGA. I don't need CEC on the other outputs. A few two port HDMI designs (1 x RX and 1 x TX) that I have seen including an FPGA separate the CEC lines for RX and TX to the FPGA (before and after a level shifter), however CEC lines are connected through a 0R resistors at the connectors.

You can't connect multiple outputs together.
If you don't need CEC in the remaining two outputs, you can leave them unused (by making sure it's electrical specs are correct depending on how you leave it unused) or wire it to FPGA so you can have a controller if you want.
Right now you have the one output as the "primary" which can communicate with the input devices, and your device can act like a standard CEC switch for that one TV.
